# git deploy minified assets only

Tags: angularjs, git, deployment, web-deployment

How can I create a simple deployment process using git where only my minified/concatenated js/css files are on the production server?

I am building an angularjs/laravel app with bootstrap-sass and ideally don't want to deploy any un-minified (source) files if possible. I am using bower and gulp tools as well if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to have 2 sections in your code base:

1. All the files you use for development - js, css, htmls etc (with their folder structure)
2. A folder called 'Dist' (stand for distributed)

And have a grunt task (let's call it 'grunt build') that perform set of tasks over your development code base: minified, uglified, image compression, removes unnecessary file and **put the output in Dist**.

Once grunt build is done, you need to deploy the Dist folder to production, that can be done in many ways (holding a separate git repo for production is and every new commit is a new version is a good option)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ben. As my app also includes Laravel, would my build script copy all those files to the dist folder as well? My setup may be complicated because I haven't created 2 projects, one for the backend api (laravel) and the other for the front end (angular).

Comment: We used Codeigniter in a previous project and did the same thing, we had one git project contained both but it still doesnt matter because talking about your client code you just need the dist folder to deployed. rest of the code can stay local @updog

Comment: Sorry Ben, I don't quite understand what you mean by rest of the code staying local. I am hoping to deploy the entire solution to my production server, laravel and angularjs but minified js/css only for the client code.

Comment: Do you want your preminified code to be in production (you dont have to allow access to it) or do you want to deploy the minified only?

Comment: Deploy minified only along with laravel codebase if possible. I understand what you mean though about restricting access via the web server. That's a good idea.